# Create a map callback to scale each array value by array sum

Tags: javascript, arrays

My goal is to write a callback function...

```
function proportionize(val,ind,arr){
   ...
}
```

such that when supplied to Array.prototype.map, each value in the returned array is the respective proportion of the total of the array.

**For example,**

```
let myArray = [1,2,3] // Sums to 6
let proportions = myArray.map( proportionalize ) //  [1/6, 2/6, 3/6]
```

I want this to be...

- **self-contained** - I don't want to calculate the sum ahead of time
- **efficient** - I don't want to have to recalculate the sum at each iteration
- **interchangeable with other fn's** - See below edit

This problem is very simple *without* those to criteria. Even with those 3 criteria, I still get the sense there is some easy/obvious way of doing this (perhaps something like attempting to "save" the sum in some closure common to each iteration), but for some reason I'm drawing a blank. Any ideas?

**A test for a working answer...**

```
let arr = [1,2,3],
    callbacks = [Math.sqrt, Math.round, Math.sin, **proportionalize**, etc...];

for(cb in callbacks){
  console.log(arr.map(callbacks[cb]))
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Also, for reference, have a **non-answer** that "works", but I would consider a non-answer because it requires passing an argument to a function that then generates the callback. I'd like the call to map to match the call of any other function. For example...

```
// The "working" non-answer
function proportionalize(arrIn){
  let total = arrIn.reduce( (a,b)=>a+b);
  return (val,ind,arr)=>{ return val/total };
}

myArray.map(proportionalize(myArray)) // works but I'd have to call differently than...
myArray.map(Math.sqrt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can probably be asked more generally as...,

**When I call map with a given callback function, how can I create/leverage a shared state between each instance/invocation of the callback function?**. Once this question is answered, you can just use something like short-circuit evaluation to prevent calculations from being repeated needlessly.

It occurred to me that Array.prototype.map already provides this capability with the optional `thisArg`. If `this` isn't already being used, supplying an empty object, `{}`, allows the callback invocation to modify/share the same `this` without modifying state that persists beyond the lifetime of the map call.

Starting with this empty state let's you compute the total only if it has not been computed and the total is accessible at each iteration.

```
proportionalize = function(val, ind, arr){
  this.total = this.total || arr.reduce((x,y)=>x+y);
  return val/this.total;
}

let arr = [1,2,3],
    callbacks = [Math.round, proportionalize];

for(cb in callbacks){
  console.log(arr.map(callbacks[cb],{})) 
// => [1,2,3], [ 0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5 ]
}

arr = [1,2,7];
for(cb in callbacks){
  console.log(arr.map(callbacks[cb],{}))
// => [1,2,3], [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.7 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer works, but there are a few things I don't like about it...

**The approach:**

- Calculate the total on the 1st iteration only
- "Save" the total to the array, `arr.total` (it is available at each iteration)
- Use `arr.total` in map iterations
- Delete the `total` property at the last iteration before returning the array

**The code:**

```
function proportionalize(val, ind, arr){
  if(ind===0){
    arr.total = arr.reduce( (a,b)=>a+b);
  }

  let proportion = val/arr.total;

  if(ind===(arr.length-1)){
    delete arr.total;
  }

  return proportion;
}

[1,2,3].map(proportionalize) // [ 0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5 ]
```

**What I don't like:**

I'm modifying the array, adding and removing the "total" property. In general, I don't want to assume that property isn't already used for something else. That property name could be changed to a random string of letters or something, but that still feels a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `[1,2,3].map(proportionalize)` applies `proportionalize` to each element of the array. It's not an operation on the array itself, but on its elements.

Though this isn't a "map callback", your existing solution could be wrapped up as follows:

```
Array.prototype.proportionalize = function() {
  let sum = this.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
  return this.map(x => x/sum);
}
```

For example:

```
> [1,2,3].proportionalize()
[ 0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5 ]
```

Comment: This is close, but my aim is to write a function I can pass around and supply to the map function. This approach requires me to call the function differently in the same way that the answer in my edit does.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to do that to the array itself, rather than its elements. If you had a collection of arrays, then you could proportionalize each, one at a time `arrays.map(proportionalize)`. Attempting to do this while mapping over the elements of a single array likely requires you to do the things you're trying to avoid

Comment: possible use case example: `callbacks = [Math.sqrt, double, isMax, etc..., proportionalize]; for(i in callbacks){ console.log( myArray.map(i)) }`. I believe this answer would break here, but an accepted answer would not.

Comment: in that case, i think what you've done above is best, since the callback depends on the array; before dividing, you must compute the sum ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯